# É obrigatório fazer rebuild?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Sempre que eu apertava o botão Start pra executar meu programa e testar, ele executava corretamente. De um tempo pra cá, sempre que eu altero algo e executo o programa, ele não atualiza, é preciso eu clicar com o botão direito no projeto em em 'Rebuild' pra poder atualizar.

O que pode ser? Não lembro de ter mexido em nada diferente.

Comment: Verifique no menu `Build | Configuration Manager` se o `Active solution..` está `debug` e se todos projetos estão marcados como `build`

Comment: Isso mesmo @PabloVargas resolveu. Se quiser, pode escrever a resposta pra eu dar seus pontos. Abraço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifique no menu `Build | Configuration Manager` se o `Active solution..` está como `debug` e se todos projetos estão marcados como `build`